# Android openGL object translation and rotation in the same time

Tags: android, opengl-es

Using Android opengl I need to move an object from point A to point B and rotate it around its local Z axis in the same time. I have been reading tutorials for the past 3 days, everybody gives you bits of informations and hints, but nobody is capable of explaining this from top to bottom for beginners.

I know how to only translate the object from point A to point B.
I also know how to rotate the object in point A around its local axis (translate it to origin, rotate it, translate it back)
I DON'T know how to rotate and translate in the same time.

I've tried to translate to origin, rotate, translate back, then translate to point B. It doesn't work, and I think I know why (the rotation is messing the object axis, so the translation to point B is incorrect)

```
A(-x1, y1 , -z1)
B(-x1 + deltaX, y1 + deltaY, -z1 + deltaZ)
_gl.glTranslatef(x1, -y1 , z1);         
_gl.glRotatef(degrees, x1, -y1 , z1);                               
_gl.glTranslatef(-x1, y1 , -z1);
_gl.glTranslatef(deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ);
```

I need to take into consideration the way the rotation is chaning the axes. Some say I can do that with quaterninons, or with rotation matrixes, etc.
But I don't have enough opengl knowledge to use apis to resolve this.

Can someone explain this to me? With somecode also?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think I understand in full what you are trying to do. Please tell us more about the effect you are trying to achieve - is there an analogy in the real world of this spinning/flipping effect? Are you animating it, or is it a one-off, permanent operation? I thought that if you just glLoadIdentity(), then rotate, then translate, this should do in such cases..

Comment: The 1st sentence of this post says: " I need to move an object from point A to point B and rotate it around its local Z axis in the same time". The analogy in real time is this:  I have an aircraft, that has a propeller in its nose. The propeller is a separate object, that needs to rotate around its local z axis, while translating in the same time with the aircraft. I know how to only translate the propeller, I also know how to only rotate the propeller while the aircraft is not moving, but when rotating and translating in the same time, the propeller takes an unexpected trajectory.

Comment: would that work?: keep track of global translation in some variable; when drawing the "propeller": glLoadIdentity, rotate, translate locally (position of propeller on aircraft), translate globally (position of aircraft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following code:

```
glTranslate(x, y, z);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
drawObject();
```

The object will first be rotated around it's local z-axis and then translated with `(x, y, z)`. The transform call that is closest to the draw call is the one that happens first.

From your code it seems like you actually don't want to rotate the object around it's own origin but some other point, in this case you should do the following:

```
glTranslate(x, y, z);                         //Transform 4
glTranslate(origin.x, origin.y, origin.z);    //Transfrom 3
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);                    // Transform 2 
glTranslate(-origin.x, -origin.y, -origin.z); // Transform 1
drawObject();
```

Comment: "The transform call that is closest to the draw call is the one that happens first". That is the most valubale information I've learned in the past 3 days of reading forums. All my calls had to be in reverse order. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot